# PL SQL nested subquery

Tags: plsql, nested, subquery

I'm trying to get the result into a variable (is it possible to do it as a %rowtype of an existing table? probably not because of conflicting columns) where it would display me all the values where the two refs overlap and the i_ref(which is inputted ) also overlaps with the ref from t1.

```
select *
  into   aRow
  from   table1 t1
where  t1.ref = i_ref
  and  (select * from table2 t2 where t1.ref = t2.ref);
```

What am I doing wrong with my select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join tables instead of nested subquery:

```
select t1.*
into aRow
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.ref = t2.ref
where t1.ref = i_ref
```

Comment: If i didn't also had the input value(that is inputted by the user every time) (t1.ref = i_ref) that would work yes

Comment: @William added `where t1.ref = i_ref`

Comment: Thanks that worked! now i need to find out why although it works in the SQL it doesn't allow me to put into aRow